# Отправка POST запроса на страницу request payload

Tags: c#, post

Мне необходимо реализовать авторегистрицию на сайте. Во время регистрации отловил что на сервер уходят вот такие данные :

```
{method: "Somesite::Id::register_user",…}
method
:
"Somesite::Id::register_user"
params
:
[{firstname: "тестетстест", lastname: "тестетстет", gender: "f", username: "testetste",…}]
0
:
{firstname: "тестетстест", lastname: "тестетстет", gender: "f", username: "testetste",…}
answer
:
"23445565"
birthday
:
5270400
create_session
:
1
domain
:
"Somesite.ru"
firstname
:
"тестетстест"
gender
:
"f"
geoid
:
0
lastname
:
"тестетстет"
password
:
"qwerty123"
question
:
"Почтовый индекс ваших родителей"
username
:
"testetste"
utm
:
{,…}
via
:
{project: "id", type: "self"}
__rpcOrderId
:
"recaptcha"
__rpcOrderValue
:
"03ANcjosrr2Xy_WuLv2RQEs7o9-G5d6uPCI60FM4RZpdXJRp6jyD_z9LnfCxP5qnIEa4isQM01CoWmif45bJ60IaPS5t5YR9fz1l4t0b5FI3h_--G176WOm6UBw_qIZP7Gu6LxwFUJuyg0jkkUIUDYNNGL_KAtmszTVG20xKGM0KHHFjhKO7c1HqTeD7t50yv0YTy_TAnK4zhV0ZBzmBlT2ZbAPkahdulEXSb2ffzYub8jvYZa9k8G8fAVdIPOHKMVRAEALS0G5ax5bze20WovCiwtzl59zSjlu0t22y1Q2HyQd9a02c7G_8YPA8ocnUxA4hcfZNkMlNhstTMHeEvX788qmfv-i4jIx03EciFVh1LLpn90WkjP7x-_qvDtLKVT2vfvG7zCBSyC8wZaXvUk65lu5tOUup6CUHKifYmLeVPBfDvP-R1GwnZbMxwAdjsjQCUOzP24zsB7"
__secId
:
"37vqIspl"
__vrtRid
:
"GR6Qgt7r"
__vrtUid
:
"3ePrZSf2"
rpc
:
"2.0"
```

Вопрос, как имитировать отправку такого POST запроса средствами C#?(не считая капчи).  Я пытался так :

```
private void ToSendData()
{
    using (WebClient webclient = new WebClient())
    {
        webclient.Encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(1251);
        webclient.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.2; .NET CLR 1.0.3705;)");

        string url = "https://somesite/account/#register";
        string result = "";

        NameValueCollection data = new NameValueCollection();
        data.Add("firstname1", "name");
        var response = webclient.UploadValues(url, "POST", data);
        string answer = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(response);



        MessageBox.Show(answer);
    }
}
```

Когда форма примитивная то указанный выше код работает. Я первый раз встречаю `Request Payload`.

Comment: В вашем вопросе нет конкретики, поясню : без исходного кода сайта на котором вы пытаетесь регистрировать аккаунты ничего сказать нельзя. Вы отловили пост , а как он формируется понятия не имеете . Как обрабатывается в браузере , и на стороне сервера , есть ли шифрованный js который взаимодействует с сервером . Вы пытаетесь отправить готовый пост с данными о существовании которых сервер может даже не знать.
P/s здесь принято задавать конкретный вопрос по коду или решению , но никак не решение вашей проблемы в целом.

Comment: @DigitalCore если бы я знал как он формируется и/или имел доступ к исходникам сайта, я вопрос вообще не создавал бы. Я не ищу решения проблемы в целом, я ищу метод/способ отправки подобного POST запроса через Request Payload. Мне очень жаль, что мой вопрос задел ваши чувства построителя правильных вопросов.

Comment: :-) `request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";`

Comment: Берёшь fiddler, сравниваешь и подгоняешь, пока не получится.